# How do I get the number of bins in a plotly histogram?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Suppose I have a plotly histogram, which uses the size parameter and disables autobinx:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

histFig = go.Figure()
histFig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=data, name='blah'
xbins=dict(
    size=nbins)
    autobinx=False
))
```

Does go.Histogram have an internal variable that gives me the number of bins that are displayed on this plot?

Comment: The code above is a bit confusing because you’re assigning `nbins` to `size` ... intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn’t. The binning calculations happen on render in Javascript.

You can basically do the calculation yourself though: range/size.

Comment: Edited to note how you can get the number anyway :)